# How to run a IF() conditional when cloning a table using #all in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

Let's say that I have this basic table structure:

```
| Name    | Employee  |
|---------------------|
| Tom     | Nancy     |
|---------------------|
| Liz     | Jim       |
|---------------------|
```

And I want to do a `if()` on this while cloning the table into another sheet to run functions on. For example:

`=IF("Tom", "It's Tom", tbl_source[#All])`

This doesn't work even though if I use other methods to clone the content and iterate over top of them will still be incurring the same compute cost and removing the structured data. Any ideas?

Comment: Your `logical_test` argument does not return a Boolean, so why would you expect your `IF` statement to work?  Something like `=IF(tbl_source[#All]="Tom","It's Tom",tbl_source[#All])`

Answer (score 0):

`=SUBSTITUTE(tbl_source[#All], "Tom", "It's Tom")`

I was able to get it working using substitute. Unfortunate that it doesn't seem to allow `IF()` to work the same way.